# to Array from Textarea. что не так?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
    <textarea name="ta" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" value= "">45, 85, 75, 6, 5,</textarea> <br>
    <button type= "button", onclick ="getMinOfArray(Array)">MINIMUM</button><br><br><br>
    <button type="button", onclick ="getMaxOfArray(Array)">MAXIMUM</button><br />
    <script type= "text/javascript">
        var Array = parceInt(document.getElementById("textarea").value); 
        function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
            document.write ("Cамая маленькая цыфра в массиве: " + Math.min.apply(null, numArray));
        }

        function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
            document.write("Cамая большая цыфра в массиве: " + Math.max.apply(null, numArray));
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: как ты думаешь, что возвращает функция `parseInt`, в которой у тебя, кстати, опечатка?

Comment: это на всякой случай. вроде если не поможет то не мешает точно, не так?

Comment: Просто ответь на вопрос :-) _что возвращает функция `parseInt`_?

Comment: цифра ) так в чем проблема)

Comment: Функция parseInt() принимает строку в качестве аргумента и возвращает целое число в соответствии с указанным основанием системы счисления.

Comment: не цифра, а число :-) и как ты хочешь найти минимум/максимум, если у тебя есть всего **одно** число? :-D

Comment: Ааааааа понял кажется. ну а что использовать?

Comment: var Array = document.getElementById("textarea").value; так тоже не работает

Comment: конечно :-) ведь value - это всегда строка

Comment: а как делать? ты ведь знаешьъ

Answer (score 3):

В коде можно выделить несколько ошибок:

1. опечатка: нет функции `parceInt`, есть [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
2. неудачное имя переменной `Array`, совпадающее со встроенным классом [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
3. сохранение в переменную *одного* числа, вместо списка чисел
4. получение значения из `textarea` всего один раз при загрузке страницы.

Вместо этого нужно из строки, полученной от textarea (`document.getElementById("textarea").value`) вытащить нужные числа, например с помощью [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): `document.getElementById("textarea").value.match(/(\d+)/g)`

К результату можно сразу применить функции `min`/`max`, так как они сами пытаются преобразовать свои аргументы к числам.

В итоге может получиться следующее:

```js
function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
  var numbers = document.getElementById("textarea").value.match(/\d+/g) || []; //на случай если чисел нет
  document.write("Самая маленькая цифра в массиве: " + Math.min(...numbers));
}

function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  var numbers = document.getElementById("textarea").value.match(/\d+/g) || []; //на случай если чисел нет
  document.write("Самая большая цифра в массиве: " + Math.max(...numbers));
}
```

```html
<textarea name="ta" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" value="">45, 85, 75, 6, 5,</textarea> <br>
<button type="button" , onclick="getMinOfArray()">MINIMUM</button><br><br><br>
<button type="button" , onclick="getMaxOfArray()">MAXIMUM</button><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Всегда полученные значения из полей формы имеют тип `string`.
2. Посмотрите как преобразуется массив в `javascript` [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)

Вот пример рабочего кода, но оно будет нормально работать если после каждой написанной цифры вставить одинаковый разделитель, у нас это будет `,`.

Код работает так, разделяет `value` на `,`, и получается массив у которого типы элементов `string`, потом явно преобразуем типы элементов в массиве, и после этого только передаем в функцию.

```html
<textarea name="ta" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" value= "">45, 85, 75, 6, 5</textarea> <br>
<button type= "button", onclick ="getMinOfArray(Array)">MINIMUM</button><br><br><br>
<button type="button", onclick ="getMaxOfArray(Array)">MAXIMUM</button><br />
<script type= "text/javascript">
    var Array = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    Array = Array.split(', ');
    for(var i=0; i<Array.lengt;i++){
        Array[i] = parseFloat(Array[i]);
    }
    function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
        
        document.write ("Cамая маленькая цыфра в массиве: " + Math.min.apply(null, numArray));

    }

    function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
        
        document.write("Cамая большая цыфра в массиве: " + Math.max.apply(null, numArray));

    }

</script>
```

Comment: спасибо всем. hesa porcem exbayr

Comment: @user255352 Не за что.

Comment: может я тут неправильно написалб но мне интересует именно то чтоб ползователь смог в текстарее писать свои цифры....

Comment: да почему цыфра если цифра

Comment: @Duoxx, потому что код автора вопроса.

Comment: а вот не подскажете метод чтобы сложить цифры таким образом? пр. 15 = 1+5 = 6 или 584 = 5+8+4 = 17

Answer (score 0):

Нужно грамотно преобразовать полученные данные из массива в числа, и после этого их перебирать

```html
<body>
<textarea name="ta" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" value= "">45, 85, 75, 6, 5</textarea> <br>
<button type= "button", onclick ="getMinOfArray()">MINIMUM</button><br><br><br>
<button type="button", onclick ="getMaxOfArray()">MAXIMUM</button><br />
<script type= "text/javascript">
    
function getMinOfArray() {
    let arr = document.getElementById("textarea").value.split(', ');
    document.write ("Cамая маленькая цыфра в массиве: " + Math.min.apply(null, arr));
}

function getMaxOfArray() {
    let arr = document.getElementById("textarea").value.split(', ');
    document.write("Cамая большая цыфра в массиве: " + Math.max.apply(null, arr));
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: если ты уберешь строчку `arr.forEach(item => item = parseFloat(item));` из своего кода - ничего не поменяется

Comment: В данном случае вместо forEach Надо было использовать `map`, так как тебе нужна _новая коллекция_ из цифр. На данный момент, ты парсишь строки, присваиваешь локальной переменной и далее у тебя это значение теряется.

Comment: согласен, забыл убрать, когда правил код) спасибо

Comment: В любом случае, стоит внимательнее быть при выборе `map` или `forEach`

Comment: в каком месте у меня что теряется? что-то понять не могу.

Comment: В цикле, который ты убрал (пример в моем первом комментарии). Он бесполезен, и не оказывал влияния на массив, к которому применялся. Именно поэтому его удаление никак не сказалось на работоспособности сниппета

Comment: почему `цыфра` если `цифра`

Comment: @Duoxx, потому что код автора вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
<textarea name="ta" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" value= "">45, 85, 75, 6, 5</textarea> <br>
<button type= "button", onclick ="getNumber('min', 'Cамая маленькая цыфра в массиве: ')">MINIMUM</button><br><br><br>
<button type="button", onclick ="getNumber('max', 'Cамая большая цыфра в массиве: ')">MAXIMUM</button><br />
<script type= "text/javascript">
    
function getNumber(mode, comment) {
    var method = Math[mode];
    if (!method) return;
    var arr = document.getElementById("textarea")
                      .value
                      .split(',')
                      .map(function(value){
                          return parseInt(value);
                      });
    document.write ((comment || '') + method.apply(null, arr));
}
</script>
</body>
```